# Using a self-signed certificate to create a secure client-server connection in android

Tags: android, security, ssl

I am developing an enterprise android application, thus it is necessary to create a secure connection between the client (android emulator / test phone) and server during my testing phase, even though the server's certificate is self-signed while a legitimate certificate is being bought by the company (something outside my control for now).

I need to trust the server's self-signed certificate and its certificate-authority, which is not trusted by the android OS natively, of course.  I am following [google's suggestion for creating an HTTPS environment in this scenario](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa) almost verbatim.

The problem I'm currently facing is that I can't access my `.crt` file as in this line from google's example:

```
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(
    new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));
```

In place of the above, I am using:

```
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mycrtfile));
```

to open the `InputStream` derived from `mycrtfile.crt`, where the `.crt` file exists in `/res/raw/mycrtfile.crt`.  However, I get a `NullPointerException` on that line.

Is there a better way to store and access the cert file which I need to load as an `InputStream` or `FileInputStream` than as a raw resource stored inside the `res` directory?

Comment: I had the same problem check my answer and if you are confused on the steps I can help you. This will accept only your certificate.

Comment: Thanks @Moises, I'm done working on that project for the day, so I'll look through the solution tomorrow and let you know if I get stuck.

Answer (score 7):

There is different ways to solve your problem but here is the one I use:
All the steps are in this link http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/  but some parts  can be confused so I will explain all the process:

1.-Store your mycrtfile.crt in a know path I will say c:BKS/mycrtfile.crt.

2.-To create your BKS or key store you will need the file bcprov-jdk15on-146.jar, this class will do all the work for us, there are different versions but this one works for me http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk15on-146.jar also store this file into C:BKS/

3.-Now you will use the Keytool (keytool comes with the Java SDK. You should find it in the directory that contains javac) to generate our keystore and to make sure that is working go to your cmd and type "Keytool", you will see the available commands which means is working, or you can access trough "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin>keytool".

4.-Now that everything is in place we can generate the keystore with this command line:

keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "c:\BKS/mycrtfile.crt" -alias certificate  -keystore "c:\BKS/keystore.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "c:\BKS/prov-jdk15on-146.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass mysecret

Lets see what is in this line (I was really confused in this part):
-"c:\BKS/mycrtfile.crt" : this is the path to your certificate.
-"c:\BKS/keystore.bks" this is the path where we will store the keystore and you can change the out-put name I use keystore, just make sure that the extension file is .bks
-"c:\BKS/prov-jdk15on-146.jar": this is the path to our file that will do all the job. 
-mysecret: this is the password to use the key store you will need this password so don't forget about this.

**EDITED:**
4.1- Also use this command line to Verify if the certificate were imported correctly into the keystore:

keytool -list -keystore "res/raw/Keystore.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "c:\BKS/prov-jdk15on-146.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass mysecret

4.2- After this you should see a output like this:

RootCA, 22.10.2010, trustedCertEntry, Thumbprint (MD5): 24:77:D9:A8:91:D1:3B:FA:88:2D:C2:FF:F8:CD:33:93
IntermediateCA, 22.10.2010, trustedCertEntry, Thumbprint (MD5): 98:0F:C3:F8:39:F7:D8:05:07:02:0D:E3:14:5B:29:43 
Which means it was imported correctly.

5.- After this if you go to your BKS folder you will se a Keystore.bks file which means we are on the way.

6.- Now lets go to the ANDROID part. IN your project check if you have the "raw" folder it has to be in Yourproject/res/raw if not create this folder under res.

7.-copy your Keystore.bks file in to the raw folder. Everything is on place now lets go to the code.

8.--- Now we will create a class to read and trust  our Keystore:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

import com.futureconcepts.anonymous.R;
import android.content.Context;


public class Client extends  DefaultHttpClient   {
final Context context;
  public Client(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
      SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
      registry.register(new Scheme("http", 
      PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
      // Register for port 443 our SSLSocketFactory with our keystore
      // to the ConnectionManager
      registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(),443));

    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
     HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,9000);
     HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 9000);

      return new SingleClientConnManager(httpParams, registry);
  }


  private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
      try {

          // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
            KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");//put BKS literal  
            // Get the raw resource, which contains the keystore with
            // your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
            InputStream in =context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);
            try {
                // Initialize the keystore with the provided trusted certificates
                // Also provide the password of the keystore
                trusted.load(in, "mysecret".toCharArray());
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }
          // Pass the keystore to the SSLSocketFactory. The factory is responsible
          // for the verification of the server certificate.
          SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
          // Hostname verification from certificate

           sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
          return sf;
      } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new AssertionError(e);
      }
  }

}
```

9.And we done now to make a request just do this:
    HttpClient client= new Client(this);
    ///setupo your Httpclient.

That's it now you will only trust your certificate. I hope this explanation help you or any one with the same problem.

Comment: I had some trouble with the above link at first.  I was able to get a quick solution looking at [this](http://paxbat-android.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-https-and-not-trusted-server.html) guide to configure HTTPS in my app.   My worry, however, is that this is just disabling all checks on the SSL and some malicious third party could inject its own third party cert.

Comment: I don't think it is a good Idea just disable the validation for self signed certificates,  the best you can do is trust just your certificate, if the purpose of this is have some security once you create a request, otherwise you can accept all the certificates (which I think is a really bad idea, but it can be done). The link I give you will guide you to create a keystore for your certificate and you will only trust that certificate, I will explain all the process just give me some time. It seems complicated but is not and is the right way to do accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the more extensive explanation.  I am looking further into this.

Comment: If I use a different port on the SSL server, say `6565`, than the default (`443`), should I change the port to `6565` in this code?

Comment: I tried using my own custom port (`6565`, for example) and `443` in the above code and neither is working.  I followed the instructions, but it's still giving a `Not trusted server certificate` error...weird.

Comment: I create the certificate on the server and Im using the default port which is 443 if you are using a different one you should change this also if you can post how you set the request so I can help you. Also did you change "mysecret" for the  password you put?

Comment: I came through your answer while researching on using self-signed certificates for my application. I understood the process, but I have few questions/doubts. The file `mycrtfile.crt` that you said, is it the certificate file that I'll receive from the server or will I need to generate it? I have a self-signed certificate on my server, so will I need it to generate the BKS file for my android application? If, yes how can I use that?

Comment: Hello Moy, What about the nginx part on my server? Does nginx certificate have to be the same as the bks one?

Answer (score 0):

[Keystore](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html) (Here is a great [article](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/05/storing-application-secrets-in-androids.html) on Keystore and related issues)  and [KeyChain](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html) do the trick but you might need to check the API level you targeting with. Furthermore, since you mentioned Enterprise Application, you may need to consider Certificate pinning. [This](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) helps you for the certificate pinning.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create directory "assets" in app/src/main/

2) Put your certificate in this directory.

3) Now you can get InputStream  :

```
InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("mycrtfile.crt");
```

To you use this.getAssets() you have to be in Activity, because in Activity "this" correspond to the "Context".
If you are not in Activity you have to pass the Context (this) as argument.