# Self signed certificate for mobile app and backend from same company

Tags: security, certificate, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, self-signed

My company's product is Android and iOS mobile app which connects to our own backend. All interactions of the mobile app are with backend developed by our own company.

In such a situation, can the backend use a self signed certificate (instead of getting a certificate from CA) and pin this self-signed certificate on mobile app to make it more secure.

Please let me know if this strategy makes sense (or we still have to get SSL cert from a CA)

Comment: Yes, you _can_ use a self signed cert, but it is a bunch of work to configure Android to trust it.  A real SSL cert from a known CA would be trusted automatically by Android.

Comment: Yes you can do it, here there is a similar question that does it. In this question it seems they keep the keystore in the res/raw, though I have seen a slightly different solution where you just keep the certificate in res/raw and you load it into a in memory keystore. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346249/using-a-self-signed-certificate-to-create-a-secure-client-server-connection-in-a

Comment: If you decide to go the self-signed route make sure to have a plan in place for if/when you need to renew or replace the certificate. Otherwise you might end up locking out users with an old version of the app, with no way to notify them that an app upgrade is required.

Comment: @StefanOS ..thank you for the heads up. Would certificate pinning on clients not help here. More particularly, only pinning the key (not the certificate) on the client side. By only pinning the key and not certificate, the certificate can change (but the keys have to remain same)

Comment: Yes that's possible and would solve the problem of an expired cert. But I would then generate an extra key, not use it just keep it safe - then include it in the allowed pinned keys in the app. Because the original key might get compromised or even lost.

Comment: I'd prefer using your own ca. Keep in mind that self-signed certificates and custom ca need to lösen the ATS in IOS.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue, but I think it bears following up on. SSL certs are dirt cheap if purchased from the right companies and not from the "big 3". Comodo has wildcard certs (any subdomain) for USD 60-70/year. They are secure (256 SHA) and install right off. Well worth the money, IMHO.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should contact the SSL support team for a signed certificate
I believe they can give you a solution to update your SSL or need to update for a new certificate